# Write $e^{\ln(5)}i$ in polar and rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there something I'm missing? Below is my attempt, but I feel as though I might have missed something to learn about complex numbers when $r=e^n$.

$$|ie^{\ln(5)}|=e^{\ln(5)}$$
$$\theta=\arctan(\frac{e^{\ln(5)}}{0})=\text{undefined}; \text{thus}, \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$z=e^{\ln(5)}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=e^{\ln(5)+i\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: $e^{\ln(\text{whatever})}=\text{whatever}$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD facepalm.jpg..... Ah!!! How did I not see that!? Thank you!!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I wonder if we'll see that as the new nerdslacker response to anything.  "Hey, I've got tickets to see Broom Monkeys!"  "$e^{\ln(\text{whatever})}$."

Comment: @BrianTung Haha, you made me laugh, that'd be fun :'$)$.

Comment: @BrianTung righteous lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z$ be your number.

Sometimes it's easier to figure out the angle just visualizing the number in the plane, for $i$ it's particularly easy, as it lies in an axis perpendicular to the real line, we can infer that it's $\frac \pi 2 $.

As $e^{\ln 5}=5$, we have that $|z|=|5i|=|5|\cdot |i|=5 \cdot 1$.

And $\arg(z)=\arg(5i)=\arg(5)+\arg(i)=0+\frac \pi 2.$

So $z=5e^{i\frac\pi 2}=0+5i$.

I've used a few properties ($|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|, \arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$) which proofs I leave as exercise.

Comment: Free rep for you, eh? Haha thanks all the same! :)